# comma(,) separating string while exporting to XL in CSV format c#

Tags: c#, export-to-csv, string.format

I am a beginner in C#, I am exporting some data to XL sheet in CSV format. My data contains a fullname column in which data is like (John, Delores "Sutton"). When I export this to XL it is dividing the data into two columns(or tabs) like Tab1: John and Tab2: Delores "Sutton" because of Comma(,). I want

If I use the below code

```
string F1 = base.GetColumnText(column, columnValue); //ex: John, Delores \"Sutton\""
string F2 = string.Format("\"{0}\"", F1); //ex: "\"John, Delores\"Sutton\"\""
streamWriter.Write(F2); //ex output in XL is: John, Delores Sutton""
```

The output in XL is:

> John, Delores Sutton""

But I want it as :

> John, Delores "Sutton"

Comment: why not export the data as pipe delimeted or tab delimeted to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have double-double quotes to represent double quotes in a CSV, *and* everything must be surrounded by double quotes so your output in text will look like:

```
"John, Delores ""Sutton"""
```

So you will need to do a find and replace on the text to double your double quotes...

```
F1 = F1.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
```

Then do your format to surround text with quotes.

```
var F2 = string.Format("\"{0}\""), F1);
```

Savvy?

Comment: Awesome It's perfect! Thanks a lot for the fast reply. I haven't expected this fast. You guys are the best.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since commas are used to delimit fields, values with commas are interpreted as two fields. Such fields must be enclosed in quotes. As a result, fields that contain quotes must also be enclosed in quotes, and each quote within the field must be doubled up.

There are a number of rules for creating CSV files. I've written a very complete class for reading and writing CSV files and present the code in my article [Reading and Writing CSV Files in C#](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c). You might want to check that out.